# Maximizing $ P\{X=Y\}$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X\sim \text{Binomial}(N = 100, p=0.5)$

$Y\sim \text{Binomial}(N = 120, p=0.5)$

What is the  largest possible numerical value of $P\{X=Y\}$. $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to pick a probability space and random variables $X$ and $Y$ on it as above such that $P(X=Y)$ is as large as possible. Is that right?

Comment: yes. but X and Y have to be of the given binomial distributions.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "as above."

Comment: oops. didn't quiet read that properly. my apologies.

Comment: If they are 'not necessarily independent', then you have not specified the problem. Please specify the joint pmf of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: i believe we are free to choose a dependance that will perform the maximization.

Comment: @ava I *think* I have a proof for when $X$ can be written as $X = f(Y)$ for some $f$, but it relies pretty heavily on computer calculations. Would that interest you?

Comment: @Ant I'm not Ava and it is of course her decision what kinds of answers she wants to receive, but I wouldn't award the bounty for an answer to that question.

Comment: The 400-point bounty will be going to Did once the system allows me to give it to him. I meant to give Ewan and Did equal amounts, but once I'd awarded the 200 to Ewan, the system would only allow me to award an additional 400 points for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

A general result is that the *minimal* possible value of $P(X\ne Y)$ is $$\frac12\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|p_X(k)-p_Y(k)|.$$
This number is the [total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between the distribution $(p_X(k))_k$ of $X$ and the distribution $(p_Y(k))_k$ of $Y$, and the result explains the logic of @Ewan's computations.

Thus, the maximal possible value of $P(X=Y)$ is $$1-\frac12\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|p_X(k)-p_Y(k)|=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\min\{p_X(k),p_Y(k)\}.$$

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this fact?

Comment: @user180040 Anything on coupling, say the first chapter of Lindvall's book. Or the second reference on the WP page I linked to (the WP link to the first one seems dead).

Comment: Here is the [link](http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Coupling-Method-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486421457) to the Lindvall's book on amazon.

Comment: This is a good answer. The Google Books link from the Wikipedia article answers the question (in conjunction with Ewan's lemma). Specifically, Propositions 4.2 and 4.7 of *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres and Wilmer, beginning at page 47.

Comment: @user180040 Thanks for the (bounty and the) appreciation.

Answer (score 5):

The exact answer is

$$M=\sum_{k=0}^{55} \frac{\binom{120}{k}}{2^{120}}+
\sum_{k=56}^{100} \frac{\binom{100}{k}}{2^{100}} \approx 0.3413$$

We show first that $M$ is an upper bound : we have

$$
P(X=Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{100}P(X=Y=k)
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{55}P(Y=k)+\sum_{k=56}^{100}P(X=k)=M. \tag{1}
$$

Let us now show that $M$ is attained. For ease of notation,  put

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_i &=& P(X=i)=\frac{\binom{100}{i}}{2^{100}} \ (0\leq i\leq 100),\\
x_i &=& 0 \ (101\leq i \leq 120), \\
y_j &=& P(Y=j)=\frac{\binom{120}{j}}{2^{120}} \ (0\leq j\leq 120), \\
A&=& \sum_{i=0}^{55}(x_i-y_i)=\sum_{j=56}^{120}(y_j-x_j)\\
\end{array}
\tag{2}
$$

Note that the last equality follows from $\sum_{i=0}^{120}x_i=\sum_{j=0}^{120}y_j=1$.

**Lemma.** We have $y_k\leq x_k$ for $1\leq k \leq 55$ and $x_k\leq y_k$ for $56\leq k \leq 120$.

The lemma is shown at the end of this answer. We now explain how it is used : define
a map $\pi : \lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots,100\rbrace \times \lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots,120\rbrace \to {\mathbb R}$ by

$$
\pi(i,j)=
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
y_k & \text{if} & i=j=k,\ 0\leq k \leq 55 \\
\frac{(x_i-y_i)(y_j-x_j)}{A}   & \text{if} & 0\leq i \leq 55, 56\leq j \leq 120 \\
x_k & \text{if} & i=j=k,\ 56\leq k \leq 100, \\
0 & \text{otherwise} &
\end{array}\right.
$$

It follows easily from the lemma that $\pi\geq 0$ and $\sum_{j}\pi(i,j)=x_i$, $\sum_{i}\pi(i,j)=y_j$,$\sum_{i,j}\pi(i,j)=1$, so that
$\pi$ is a probability distribution. We are then done, by considering $Z=(X,Y)$, a random variable with values in
$\lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots,100\rbrace \times \lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots,120\rbrace$ and
distributed according to $\pi$.

**Proof of lemma.** Let $u_k=\frac{y_k}{x_k}$. We have $u_k=\frac{1}{2^{20}}\prod_{j=101}^{120}\frac{j}{j-k}$, 
and hence $\frac{u_{k+1}}{u_k}=\frac{120-k}{100-k}$, so that the sequence $u_k$ is increasing. We conclude by
noticing that $u_{55}<1$ and $u_{56}>1$.

Comment: Could you explain why $A + B = 1$?

Comment: @user180040 It was $A=B$ actually, not $A+B=1$. Corrected now, thanks.

Comment: Nice answer! I think you just need to correct some occurrences of $k=1$ to $k=0$, and reverse the inequalities in the statement of the lemma. I also think that it would be helpful to mention the fact that $\sum_j \pi(i,j) = x_i$ and $\sum_i \pi(i,j) = y_j$, since this is crucial to the proof.